# how can my command wait till there's an input from Read-Host?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this simple script to get information from AD for a user.
This is my code so far..

```
$name = Read-Host 'Cual es el usuario a buscar?' 
(Get-ACL "AD:$((Get-ADUser $name).distinguishedname)").access | select identityreference, accesscontroltype | Out-File C:\$name.txt
```

If i do this in 2 separate parts: $name = Read-Host  it stores the value and then i can run the following part of the code, but that's doing it manually.. if i try doing all at once seems like it doesn't wait to get an input and doesn't work.. i've tried putting the code in 1 line but doesn't work either.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Read-Host is a blocking operation, it can't continue unless you break or give it some data.

Comment: My bad it asks for the input but after that it displays this message.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ((Get-ACL "AD:$(...le C:\$name.t
   xt:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: '(Get-ACL "
   AD:$((Get-ADUser $name).distinguishedname)").access | select identityrefer
  ence, accesscontroltype | Out-File C:\$name.txt' under: 'DC=dz,DC=azo,DC=company,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Cual es el usuario a buscar?: user1

Comment: Are you asking how you can put two instructions on one line? That can be achieved by separating them with a semicolon.

Comment: And please don't post code or extended error messages in comments. It becomes unreadable. Edit your question if you need to provide additional information.

Comment: wow i added the semicolon and it worked just fine, seems like i was missing it.. now i'll just have to figure out how to name the out-file as the variable $name ($name.txt) but i can do that later, thanks a lot!!.